# What does this regex mean?

Tags: php, regex

```
/\n\s*\n/s
```

I think it means

- a new line
- followed by 0 or more spaces
- then a new line

This this correct? If not, can you explain?

Comment: What regular expression parser are you using? For which language and/or which library? You may want to add some tags about that.

Comment: @Roalt, I already had PHP tagged, but I guess someone removed it. Will add it back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Almost right: `\s` actually means "any whitespace character" which also includes tabs and possibly CR/LF (`\r` and `\n`).

If you are using perl, `\s` may match some other characters too (from [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)):

> If Unicode is in effect, "\s" matches also "\x{85}", "\x{2028}, and "\x{2029}"

A couple more clarifications.

- Because the match isn't anchored (`^` at the beginning or `$` at the end), most engines treat this expression to mean that the string can match ANYWHERE within the string. In other words, the regex `/cat/` would match "cat", "caterpillar", or "concatenate". So your string needs to CONTAIN what you described, but can be prefixed or suffixed by anything else.
- The `/s` at the end generally means to treat the whole string as one giant line. Again, from perlre:

> Treat string as single line.  That is, change "." to match any character whatsoever, even a newline, which normally it would not match.
>
> The "/s" and "/m" modifiers both override the $* setting.  That is, no matter what $* contains, "/s" without "/m" will force "^" to match only at the beginning of the string and "$" to match only at the end (or just before a newline at the end) of the string.  Together, as /ms, they let the "." match any character whatsoever, while still allowing "^" and "$" to match, respectively, just after and just before newlines within the string.

Comment: Be extremely wary about bugs if you're using php, too: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11528

Answer (score 1):

Wrong. `\s` is any whitespace character, not just space.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is mostly correct with one change and one omission.

First, as others have said, the `\s` means any whitespace, not just "a space."

Also, the trailing `s` means that the regex is in "single-line mode" which means that a `.` (dot) would match newlines.  In other words, anything you pass to this regex will be parsed as if it was a single line of input, whether or not it has line breaks (they will appear as just another special character, like `\n` or `\r`).